# how to install glassfish server as a windows service

Tags: glassfish

I have installed glassfish on the C:\ drive in Windows, and created a new domain in the E:\, needless to say I do not use the default 'domain1' as my application domain. Now I need to create a windows service that will point my new application domain instead of the default domain. Running the **asadmin create-service** command creates a windows service based on the default glassfish domain (the one in the C:\ drive). What options do I need to pass to this command so that the windows service points to my new domain?

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically `create-service --domaindir e:\.... <domainname>`. Although for me it doesn't work. It starts up my domain, but I am unable to stop the domain, unless i kill off the process manually. Neither from the windows service manager, neither with an asadmin command...